# wordpress creatin full width

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am working with wordpres theme sydney and I have download the  page builder siteOrigin to help me design my front page.

I have different sections including a team, partners and some more.
The problem I have is that I cant get this to be of full length- the image below:[image]

I have also download the plugin full width, but that didnt help, my question is if I have to change this from the css file or not. is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Is it inside a container?

Comment: @C.Schubert its inside a `div` with a class `container content-wrapper ` and then later inside a `div row `

Comment: @karankalimi, Can you share your code here so I will be able to help you.

Comment: @GufranHasan how can I share my code with you? I amw orking with wordpres!

Comment: Is your code on live? if live then you can share just site url?

Comment: @GufranHasan do u have time now so I can share it with yoiu?

Comment: @karankalimi, Tomorrow i will catch you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to costumize the css for your page. You can do this directly in Wordpress: https://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-design/editing-css/

Comment: do u know if its something with the margin that I have to changed?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding the following code to my additional CSS:

```
.page .page-wrap .content-wrapper,
.single .page-wrap .content-wrapper {
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
}
```